# How do I install Ubuntu 12 with a USB WiFi adapter?

Tags: installation, wireless, usb

I tried to install Ubuntu 12 on a Windows XP laptop that makes use of a WiFi USB adapter, but at the beginning of the installation Ubuntu says, that it cannot get some software from the net.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The internal wireless is the default and it is wlan0 but when you plug in a USB receiver it is listed as wlan1 
So, in order to install you need to compensate for seeing 2 hardware wireless components.
You need to  put wlan1 in your wireless preferences in Network Manager